# Get Current Paragraph Index

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am wanting to find the current paragraph that the user is typing in(where the caret is). **Example:** Here it would be in the 2nd Paragraph.

[image]

I know I can separate paragraphs using: `let components = textView.text.components(separatedBy: "\n")` but I am unsure how I would run a check for the current editing paragraph. Any ideas?

Comment: May be [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56579419/creating-a-cgrect-around-a-uitextview-wrong-height/56579734) will help you.

Comment: @TheTiger Doesn't really show how I would search the components for a current range...

Comment: You need current paragraph or current line?

Comment: @TheTiger Current Paragraph

Comment: How about [Get current paragraph in UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664039/get-current-paragraph-in-uitextview)

Comment: @TheTiger Well I want the count of which paragraph it's in not the range of the current paragraph.

Comment: I can help you with if there is no duplicate paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach...

Get the Y position of the caret (insertion point). Then, loop through an enumeration of the paragraphs in the textView, comparing their bounding rects to the caret position:

```
extension UITextView {

    func boundingFrame(ofTextRange range: Range<String.Index>?) -> CGRect? {

        guard let range = range else { return nil }
        let length = range.upperBound.encodedOffset-range.lowerBound.encodedOffset
        guard
            let start = position(from: beginningOfDocument, offset: range.lowerBound.encodedOffset),
            let end = position(from: start, offset: length),
            let txtRange = textRange(from: start, to: end)
            else { return nil }

        return selectionRects(for: txtRange).reduce(CGRect.null) { $0.union($1.rect) }

    }

}

// return value will be Zero-based index of the paragraphs
// if the textView has no text, return -1
@objc func getParagraphIndex(in textView: UITextView) -> Int {

    // this will make sure the the text container has updated
    theTextView.layoutManager.ensureLayout(for: theTextView.textContainer)

    // make sure we have some text
    guard let str = theTextView.text else { return -1 }

    // get the full range
    let textRange = str.startIndex..<str.endIndex

    // we want to enumerate by paragraphs
    let opts:NSString.EnumerationOptions = .byParagraphs

    var caretYPos = CGFloat(0)
    if let selectedTextRange = theTextView.selectedTextRange {
        caretYPos = theTextView.caretRect(for: selectedTextRange.start).origin.y + 4
    }

    var pIndex = -1
    var i = 0

    // loop through the paragraphs, comparing the caret Y position to the paragraph bounding rects
    str.enumerateSubstrings(in: textRange, options: opts) {
        (substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, b) in

        // get the bounding rect for the sub-rects in each paragraph
        if let boundRect = self.theTextView.boundingFrame(ofTextRange: substringRange) {

            if caretYPos > boundRect.origin.y && caretYPos < boundRect.origin.y + boundRect.size.height {
                pIndex = i
                b = true
            }

            i += 1
        }
    }

    return pIndex
}
```

Usage:

```
let paraIndex = getParagraphIndex(in myTextView)
```